# Animate in three.js a rigged model in blender

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, blender

I have a 3d model which i rigged in blender then exported it into three.js. I am trying to animate it like make it (walk, jump, run and so on).

I have tried to add controls and manipulate individual parts of the body (by moving bones). There are 42 bones in my mesh. But it doesn’t work as it needs to be. I don't want to export already animated model in blender. I need it fully animated in ThreeJS itself.

index.html

```
function init(){
    /*creates empty scene object and renderer*/
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(15, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});

    renderer.setClearColor(0x838510);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.shadowMapEnabled= true;
    renderer.shadowMapSoft = true;

    /*add controls*/
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
    controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );

    camera.position.x = -5;
    camera.position.y = 8;
    camera.position.z = 18;    
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);

    /*datGUI controls object*/
    guiControls = new function(){
        this.Bone_0 = 0.0;
        this.Bone_1 = 0.0;
        this.Bone_2 = 0.0;
        this.Bone_3 = 0.0;
        this.Bone_4 = 0.0;
        this.rotationX  = 0.0;
        this.rotationY  = 0.0;
        this.rotationZ  = 0.0;

        this.lightX = 131;
        this.lightY = 107;
        this.lightZ = 180;
        this.intensity = 1.5;       
        this.distance = 373;
        this.angle = 1.6;
        this.exponent = 38;
        this.shadowCameraNear = 34;
        this.shadowCameraFar = 2635;
        this.shadowCameraFov = 68;
        this.shadowCameraVisible=false;
        this.shadowMapWidth=512;
        this.shadowMapHeight=512;
        this.shadowBias=0.00;
        this.shadowDarkness=0.11;

        this.scene = function(){
            console.log(scene);
        };

    }


/*add loader call add model function*/
    loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load( 'modelling/LASTMODEL3.json', addModel );


    /*adds controls to scene*/
    datGUI = new dat.GUI();

    /*edit bones*/
    datGUI.add(guiControls, "scene");
    var cfolder = datGUI.addFolder('Controls');

    cfolder.add(guiControls, 'Bone_0' ,-0.1, 0.1);
    cfolder.add(guiControls, 'Bone_1' ,-0.1, 0.1);
    cfolder.add(guiControls, 'Bone_2' ,-0.1, 0.1);
    cfolder.add(guiControls, 'Bone_3' ,-0.1, 0.1);
    cfolder.add(guiControls, 'Bone_4' ,-0.1, 0.1);
function render() { 
    spotLight.position.x = guiControls.lightX;
    spotLight.position.y = guiControls.lightY;
    spotLight.position.z = guiControls.lightZ;

    scene.traverse(function(child){
        if (child instanceof THREE.SkinnedMesh){  

            child.rotation.x += 0.00;
            child.rotation.y += 0.00;
            child.rotation.z += 0.00;

            child.skeleton.bones[0].rotation.y = guiControls.Bone_0;
            child.skeleton.bones[1].rotation.z = guiControls.Bone_1;
            child.skeleton.bones[2].rotation.x = guiControls.Bone_2;
            child.skeleton.bones[3].rotation.z = guiControls.Bone_3;
            child.skeleton.bones[4].rotation.z = guiControls.Bone_4;
}
        else if  (child instanceof THREE.SkeletonHelper){
            child.update();
        }
    }); 

}
```

Here's [full code](https://jsfiddle.net/Sallivan/7mdong5p/)
And also the [model file](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/95f2c6d49dbb83b64aa407a102b426d620190105152447/7d63fe) with code

I want the mesh follow the bones as it is in blender. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: From the threejs docs on [loading 3d models](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Loading-3D-models), the threejs custom Blender exporter is no longer maintained, in favor of newer alternatives. I'd suggest trying the glTF format, with `THREE.GLTFLoader`, and the Blender 2.8 beta includes a glTF exporter by default.

Comment: @Don McCurdy Thank you for reply. But the problem is not in exporter. I don't have any problem with that.

Comment: @McCormick Listen to Dons advice. If you are using .json format for your skinnedmesh, it may simply not be usable. THREE.js has moved beyond that format and is embracing GLTF since it is a more modern format designed specifically with WebGL in mind. GLTF is a more foolproof method for getting skinned meshes into your app.